# How can i fix bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am a student and am currently beginning to learn how to code. I encountered a problem regarding my latest work with the bootstrap carousel. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Slider</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--BOOTSTRAP-->
<link href="cssboot/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--MAIN CSS-->
<link href="cssmain/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--FONT AWESOME-->
<link href="cssfont/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div>
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!--DOT NAV-->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
<!--IMGS-->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
<img class="myfullimg" src="img/1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img class="myfullimg" src="img/2.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img class="myfullimg" src="img/3.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img class="myfullimg" src="img/4.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
<!--NXT AND PREV BUTTONS-->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my main css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

.myfullimg {
width: 1347px;
height: 666px;
}
```

I am also using this css file for a different html file. That button is from bootstrap and I customized it a little.

I based my html code off of a tutorial on youtube. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FnMDubA25A&t=0s&list=PL41lfR-6DnOovY0t3nBg8Zb6aqm_H70mR&index=22

But when I run this code, the images are stacked, and there are no buttons for navigation. I also can't click the dots to navigate.

[(web page zoom out to 25%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aigdR.png)

[You can see the dot navigation but when I click it nothing happens.
(web page zoom to 100%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EljvJ.jpg)

I am using the current version of bootstrap and jquery.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with you issue on it?

Comment: here is the jsFiddle still the same : https://jsfiddle.net/b634f5mp/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues. First, and most importantly, your Bootstrap version and the markup of your carousel do not match.

I recommend using the latest of both.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.ibb.co/jzf0D5Q/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.ibb.co/q1ZW1Jh/2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.ibb.co/H4pPKmD/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://i.ibb.co/6gS07xN/4.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As a side note, you should load CSS in head and JavaScript before closing `</body>`.

Last, but not least, you're missing `popper(.min).js` (was `tether(.min).js` in older 4.* versions). Without it, Bootstrap JS (including carousel) won't work.

When in doubt, check the [official Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/) website for examples.

Answer (score 1):

At first I want you to know you use Alpha version of bootstrap, right now is available stale version 4.2.x.

Now if you want to use carousel you have to include tether.js too so your script links will be looks like

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

You can also download tehter and use it locally like you using jquery and bootstrap.bundle.

And if you will use current version of bootstrap you have to use Popper.js

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```